# Serialize XML child and keep namespaces in Java

Tags: java, dom, xml-namespaces

I have an `Document` object that is modeling a XML like this one:

```
<RootNode xmlns="http://a.com/a" xmlns:b="http://b.com/b">
    <Child />
</RootNode>
```

Using Java DOM, I need to get the `<Child>` node and serialize it to XML, but keeping the root node namespaces. This is what I currently have, but it does not serialize the namespaces:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<RootNode xmlns='http://a.com/a' xmlns:b='http://b.com/b'><Child /></RootNode>";

    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    Node childNode = doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();

    // serialize to string
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(childNode);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(sw);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
    serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    String serializedXML = sw.toString();

    System.out.println(serializedXML);
}
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Child/>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Child xmlns='http://a.com/a' xmlns:b='http://b.com/b' />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly set your `DocumentBuilderFactory` to be namespace aware:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```